# Renaming app.php to index.php making all the routes not working in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

i have renamed app.php to index.php where the routing.yml contains the following routes
index:

```
pattern:   /
defaults:  { _controller:RepairLoginBundle:home:home}
```

login:

```
pattern:   /login
defaults:  { _controller:RepairLoginBundle:Login:login}
```

when i use /

it is displaying my home page of project but when i click on login or register buuton it generating the url /login and displaying

The requested URL /rpair/login/ was not found on this server.

i want to create a default index page in symfony2 as soon as user clicks /.

This is my vhost settings

NameVirtualHost 10.70.10.56

```
ServerName repair.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/repair"
<Directory "/var/www/repair">
   DirectoryIndex app.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1
</Directory>
```

.htaccess:

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

RedirectMatch permanent ^/app.php/(.*) /$1

Comment: Can you post your vhost config and .htaccess?

Comment: i have posted my vhost and .htacccess settings please check it

Answer (score 8):

If you rename app.php to index.php you will also need change (in your `web/.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

into:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But maybe it's easier (if you have access to appropraite configuration) change your vhost settings. Just add `app.php` to `DirectoryIndex` directive.